# Autocomplete functionality for contacts module

Tags: java, html

I have an application which has a contacts module and I am using JAVA for the same.I have to implement the "Auto complete" functionality for the same. I.e., as i start typing the alphabets, search results start appearing and will eventually narrow down to the matching letter after entering the same.

Please help me with some reference JAVA code, API's and some cool stuffs to go as an add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for some example see this

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html

This one is basic example to make a auto complete.
And if you want some jazzy look and field then you can use jquery plug in client side

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html

I think this will help you.

Comment: See in auto complete feature basically there is 3 parts. 1. gui 2. ajax load 3. server response. and things you can improve -
1. gui - how jazzy u want to make.
2. ajax load - optimize your ajax call. dont often load data unless u required.or if you are showing 5 suggestion then dont load any extra data
3. server response - u can avoid db calling by cache.

Comment: a better example [http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/12/jquery-autocomplete-ajax-json-example.html](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/12/jquery-autocomplete-ajax-json-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Ajax for the same . Check out irctc.co.in , they use Ajax for station completion , quite effortlessly

Comment: ultimately the JSP will point to server side code in JAVA..that's what i want.